# Error:expression when copying from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, expression

I get an error:expression on the following code

```
    Destination:= wbfirst.Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Range("A1")
```

While the remaining code goes like this:

'provided previous month YYYYMM

```
dateFormat = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Date), "yyyymm", 1)

'workbook with the code
Set wbfirst = ThisWorkbook

'workbook that needs to be copied over from
Set wbsecond = Application.Workbooks.Open(staticFolder & "\" & dateFormat & "\" & "Source files" & "\" & "NTMR" & " - " & dateFormat & ".xlsx", _
UpdateLinks:=0)




    wbsecond.Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Range("A1:AD1105").Copy

    Destination:= wbfirst.Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Range("A1")

    Stop

    wbsecond.Close savechanges:=False

    MsgBox "You have successfully transferred the NTMR File of " & dateFormat

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
```

Suggestions on how to fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: This looks like it should be a continuation of the previous line--the one that starts "wbsecond.sheets" and ends with "copy". Go to the end of this  previous line, add a space and an underscore (_). Make sure nothing comes after the underscore. Also make sure there's not an empty line between the two.

Comment: Ahh - now I see where this `Destination:=` goes in your code - in your previous question you had the `Stop` between the `Copy` and the parameters for the `Copy`, and had only pasted up to the `Stop` into your question.  This question then becomes a "duplicate" of your last question, because Mat's Mug's answer to your last question answers this one too.

Comment: @RichHolton that did the trick.. I utilized this so that I don't get a clipboard message about copy paste. Is there a faster way to get values and format on the above function? wbsecond is basically linked to access and I don't want that in my wbfirst.